# Virtual Circuits in a narrow band network

Tags: bandwidth, virtual, atm

I know that in a broadband network a virtual circuit is established like in an X.25, frame relay and ATM. Is there a virtual circuit established in narrow band network and if yes then how is it established and maintained?

Comment: Please define *broadband network* and *narrowband network* or at least give us some context.

Comment: @Zac67 B-ISDN and N-ISDN, if that helps.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely broad, possibly due to some mixup.

All forms of ISDN use *circuit switching*, so channel resources are allocated for the entire duration of a connection. The various ISDN flavors use different kinds of B-channel signaling protocols, like DSS1 or Q.931.

A *virtual circuit* is (more or less) an emulation of a circuit-switching network over a packet-switching one. For instance, TCP can provide such a virtual circuit, or X.25.